# python2.7 netcat program running with subprocesses

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, subprocess

I am trying to make a script to mimic netcat and it kinda runs but i don't get the result i'm meant to, when trying to debug it i managed to do a bit but after days of searching and trial and errors i am at a loss at how to fix the issue. This is my whole code:

```
    import sys
import socket
import getopt
import threading
import subprocess
import os

# define the global variables
listen = False
command = False
upload = False
execute = ""
target = ""
upload_destination = ""
port = 0


def usage():
    print "BHP Net Tool"
    print "Usage: netcat2.py -t target_host -p port"
    print "-l --listen              - listen on [host]:[port] for incoming 
connections"
    print "-e --execute=file_to_run - execute the given file upon receiving 
a connection"
    print "-c --command             - initialize a command shell"
    print "-u --upload=destination  - upon receiving connection upload a 
file and wrtie to [destination]"
    print "Examples: "
    print "netcat2.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -c"
    print "netcat2.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -u=C:\\target.exe"
    print "netcat2.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\""
    print "echo 'ABCDEFGHI' | ./netcat2.py -t 192.168.0.1 -p 135"
    sys.exit(0)


def main():
    global listen
    global port
    global execute
    global command
    global upload_destination
    global target

    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()

    # read the commandline option
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hle:t:p:cu", ["help", 
 "listen", "execute", "target", "port", "command", "upload"])

    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()

    for o, a in opts:
        if o in ("-h", "--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-l", "--listen"):
            listen = True
        elif o in ("-e", "--execute"):
            execute = a
        elif o in ("-c", "--commandshell"):
            command = True
        elif o in ("-u", "--upload"):
            upload_destination = a
        elif o in ("-t", "--target"):
            target = a
        elif o in ("-p", "--port"):
            port = int(a)
        else:
            assert False, "Unhandled Option"

    # are we going to listen or just send data from stdin?
    if not listen and len(target) and port > 0:
        # read in the line from the commandline
        # this will block, so send CTRL-D if not sending input
        # to stdin
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        print (line)

        # send data off
        client_sender(line)

    # we are going to listen and potentially
    # upload things, execute commands, and drop a shell back
    # depending on our command line options above
    if listen:
        server_loop()


 def client_sender(line):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        # connect to our target host
        client.connect((target, port))

        if len(line):
            client.send(line)
        while True:

            # now wait for data back
            recv_len = 1
            response = ""

            while recv_len:

                data = client.recv(4096)
                recv_len = len(data)
                response += data

                if recv_len < 4096:
                    break

            print "response"

            # wait for more input
            line = raw_input("")
            line += "\n"

            # send it off
            client.sendline()

    except:
        print "[*] Exception! Exiting."
        # tear down the connection
        client.close()


def server_loop():
    global target

    # if no target is defined, we listen on all interfaces
    if not len(target):
        target = "0.0.0.0"

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((target, port))
    server.listen(5)

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()

        # spin off a thread to handle out new client
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_handler, args=
 (client_socket,))
        client_thread.start()


def run_command(command):
    # trim the newline
    command = command.rstrip()

    # run the command and get the output back
    try:
        with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
            output = subprocess.check_output(command, 
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    except:
        output = "Failed to execite command. \r\n"

    # send the output back to the client
    return output


def client_handler(client_socket):
    global upload
    global execute
    global command

    # check for upload
    if len(upload_destination):

        # read in all of the bytes and write to out destination
        file_line = ""

        # keep reading data until none is available
        while True:
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                break
            else:
                file_line += data

        # now we take these bytes and try to write them out
        try:
            file_descriptor = open(upload_destination, "wb")
            file_descriptor.write(file_line)
            file_descriptor.close()

            # acknowledge that we wrote the file out
            client_socket.send("Succesfully saved file to %s\r\n" % 
   upload_destination)
        except:
            client_socket.send("Failed to save file to %s\r\n" % 
   upload_destination)

    # check for command execution
    if len(execute):
        # run the command
        output = run_command(execute)

        client_socket.send(output)


    # now we go into another loop if a command shell was requested
    if command:

        while True:
            # show a simple prompt
            client_socket.send("<BHP:#> ")

            # now we receive until we see a linefeed (enter key)
            cmd_line = ""
            while "\n" not in cmd_line:
                cmd_line += client_socket.recv(1024)

            # send back the command output
            response = run_command(cmd_line)

            # send back the response
            client_socket.send(response)
            main()
```

when i run it, and close it with CTRL+D it exits and when i close the terminal i get this message in localhost:

```
<BHP:#> Failed to execite command. 
<BHP:#>
```

if anyone can help me fix this or even point me in the right direction i'd really appreciate it :), i'm trying to run this in python 2.7